# Logging Interval Java

Tags: java, logging

Is there an Java API that supports, read logs, for some kind of date/time area/range.

Example logfile:

- 01.10.2013 06:00 entry11
- 05.09.2013 06:00 entry10
- 30.08.2013 06:00 entry9
- 28.07.2013 06:00 entry8
- 17.06.2013 06:00 entry7

In this case i would like to display logs between

25.07.2013 00:00 and 06.09.2013 00:00.

So I want to get the result:

- 05.09.2013 06:00 entry10
- 30.08.2013 06:00 entry9
- 28.07.2013 06:00 entry8

Any suggestions?

Edit: The main problem is that the files are read after creation. So we need some kind of efficient "parser".

Comment: Would this help? https://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/

Comment: Maybe with the "highlight" function, I will have a look on it

Comment: The problem is that it is parsed after the creation.